# Should a linux system in FIPS mode throw failures for unsupported functions?

Tags: node.js, linux, cryptography, runtime, fips

I have a RHEL 8.6 system in FIPS mode that I'm testing what happens with containers and their runtimes when the host has FIPS=1. My expectation is that calling an unsupported cipher or method should throw some sort of error.

In my testing, I have built a NodeJS image that's been compiled with OpenSSL3.0.3 and can start the node runtime with or without fips using:

```
/opt/node/bin/node --force-fips test.js
```

or

```
/opt/node/bin/node test.js
```

When the code runs with `--force-fips` the program throws an error that I expect such as `Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`.

However, removing the `--force-fips` the code runs successfully and outputs an md5 hash `/opt/node/bin/node md5.js  b10a8db164e0754105b7a99be72e3fe5`

Since the Host is in FIPS, I thought this would be passed through and block those unsupported mechanisms like MD5 being old/unsupported in FIPS or ChaCha20 being too new and unsupported/non-validated cryptography.

What benefit does the Host FIPS mode present if the runtime can still be using ciphers and cryptography that should ultimately fail?

Answer (score 1):

The FIPS mode in the OS tells the OS-provided cryptographic libraries, such as OpenSSL, to use only FIPS-compatible ciphers and to perform additional tasks, such as a self-test on startup.

What it doesn't affect is third-party cryptographic libraries.  For example, RHEL 8.6 comes with OpenSSL 1.1.1, but your Node version is likely using a statically-compiled 3.0.3 (which, given the history of necessary security updates to OpenSSL, seems like a bad idea).  Thus, the OS didn't ship that cryptographic library and the FIPS mode of the OS wouldn't affect it.

Similarly, if you were writing Rust and used a Rust-based implementation of cryptography, or using the Go standard library for Go, then those also wouldn't be affected by the OS's FIPS mode.

Answer (score 0):

What I expect to be happening here is that the host / OS is indeed just using FIPS ciphers. However, please understand that algorithms implemented in software are not detected by the OS in any way. Neither does it know about the `force-fips` option. So you need to configure them explicitly.